# Inverted circumflex not as diacritic

Tags: math-mode, symbols, accents, superscripts

How do I typeset a caron or inverted circumflex as a character on its own in math-mode, rather than as a diacritic above another character? I need to do this because I want to use it as a superscript, like `fˇ`. This is when describing a pair of functions: `f^` and `fˇ`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you using this for? It's a nice idea.

Comment: @ssdecontrol typesetting examples from Barwise &Seligmans book on Channel Theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \text macro
\begin{document}
$f\text{\v{}}$ $f\text{\^{}}$ $f\text{\u{}}$ $f\text{\={}}$  $f\text{\.{}}$ $f\text{\"{}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I also need a subscript in places, but neither $f\text{\v{}}_T$ or $f_T\text{\v{}}$ look right -- any ideas?

Comment: @jaybee - Would `${f\text{\v{}}}_{\mkern-14mu T}$` be acceptable? The point of this admittedly not-so-pretty-looking approach is that the position of the caron isn't changed from the case without the subscript `T`.

Comment: Ugly but effective, thanks again :)

Comment: @jaybee - Just out of curiosity: Do you maybe want the accent characters to be placed a bit higher up than I do in my code?

Answer (score 4):

Adjust the amount of lowering (now 0.5ex) to suit your need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\post@accent[2]{%
  \mbox{\fontsize{#2}{\z@}\selectfont\raisebox{-0.5ex}[\dimexpr\height-0.5ex][0pt]{$\m@th\,#1{}$}}%
}
\newcommand{\definepostaccent}[2]{%
  \newcommand{#1}{\mathchoice{}{}{\post@accent{#2}{\f@size}}{\post@accent{#2}{\sf@size}}}%
}
\makeatother

\definepostaccent{\pcheck}{\check}
\definepostaccent{\pbreve}{\breve}

\begin{document}
Standard size

$f^{\pcheck}>f^{\pcheck}_{T}$ 

$f^{\pbreve}<f^{\pbreve}_{T}$

Subscript

$X_{f^{\pcheck}-f^{\pbreve}_{x}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Explanation

After `\definepostaccent{\pcheck}{\check}`, the macro `\pcheck` is defined to do

```
\mathchoice{}{}{\post@accent{\check}{\f@size}}{\post@accent{\check}{\sf@size}}
```

This means that `\pcheck` must be used only in superscripts; it will print a box where

1. the suitable font size is set: `\f@size` in first level superscripts, `\sf@size` in second level superscripts, which correspond to the normal font size and the superscript font size;
2. The box contains a 0.5ex lowered box which is given its natural height (`\height-0.5ex`) and zero depth
3. The lowered box contains the math accent, slightly shifted right.

Using `^{\pcheck}` guarantees that a subscript will be printed in its usual position.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest an alternative approach: Use $\vee$ and $\wedge$ as superscripts, like
    $f^\vee$ and $f^\wedge$.

[image: Solution using $\vee$ and $\wedge$ as superscripts]

Comment: Good call! Much simpler and though the symbols are bigger it looks fine as far as I'm concerned.